# How to animate text in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have something like this in XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout2>
            <Button>
            <Something>
        </StackLayout2>

        <Label animated>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <any content ...>
</StackLayout>
```

I want an animation to shift text from top to bottom when the button is clicked. 
During animation, the Label should be behind the stacklayout2. As if shifting from under it. The height of the AbsoluteLayout should increase. Any Content should also shift. How to implement this?

I'm specifically interested in the any content shift.

As far as I understand, animation itself is easy to implement:
    await showingText.TranslateTo(0,120, 2000);

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. It makes your post hard to read and no syntax highlighting is possible. Please provide a minimal reproducable example

Comment: @MouseOnMars Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this awesome [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypKnAKJL9CA) from Xamarin.Forms explaining how the animations work, And here is the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple)

But here is what you need to do:

### 1º - Add a Clicked event to the Button and an Identifier to the Label

```
<Button Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
<Label x:Name="labelAnimated">
```

---

### 2º - In the OnButtonClicked in the CodeBehind, add the animation

```
//Make the method async so you won't block the UI
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await labelAnimated.TranslateTo (-100, 0, 1000);    // Move image left
    await labelAnimated.TranslateTo (-100, -100, 1000); // Move image up <- you are looking for this one
    await labelAnimated.TranslateTo (100, 100, 2000);   // Move image diagonally down and right
    await labelAnimated.TranslateTo (0, 100, 1000);     // Move image left
    await labelAnimated.TranslateTo (0, 0, 1000);       // Move image up
}
```

Now to Achieve what you were looking for i did it like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentThatWillBeShifted">
        //Any type of content you want, Label, Buttons, Images (in the example used images and a label)
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        //This Content is Overlapping the other content
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Button Clicked="OnButtonClicked">
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

---

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await ContentThatWillBeShifted.TranslateTo(0, 200, 1000, Easing.BounceOut);
}
```

### The Result:

[image]

Comment: This does not result content shift

Comment: @Frendy can you me more specific then? "content" is very broad, do you want to make a label + other content shitf?

Comment: Yes, the content is under the text. By content i mean collectionView and another button

Comment: @Frendy ok give me a minute and i will add an example with an gif + code

Comment: @Frendy take a look and see if it's what you are looking for

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I also need to move this bottom block. Something like this:
https://i.imgur.com/0r2BiOv.png
https://i.imgur.com/RlxqG4c.png

Comment: And how to make a dynamic increase in grid height when shifting?

Comment: @Frendy you can use "ScaleTo" to change the grid scale, but there's others animations, check the documentation, and to move the bottom one, just use the same strategy as I did.. check the animation method parameters to see what those values represent